# UIImage retutns wrong width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uitoolbar

I have a UIImageView and I put it in a toolbar. When I run it on the simulator, the image gets stretched in. Meaning the width somehow gets less than the toolBar. Here's my code:

```
UIImageView *imageNav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                     nav.frame.size.width, nav.frame.size.height)];

nav.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageTop objectAtIndex:0]];
```

This is the output.

http://postimg.org/image/rjirnmiyx/

The yellow is the toolbar and the green thing is the image. It does not fill the toolbar.

**Update**

Whatever I do, it gets scaled off at the right side. (Like the image above.)

I tried all kinds of content modes and it all came down to one thing. Something does get ruined at the right  hand side.

**Update 2**

I figured out the problem! The problem is that the UIImageView does not have a constraint. Can someone please help me add a constraint?

Comment: try to set imageNav mode to AspectFit

Comment: What is the size of image?

Comment: The size is 320 x 44, which is the same size as the toolbar

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
[imageNav sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageTop objectAtIndex:0]]

UIImageView *imageNav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                 image.size.width, image.size.height)];

imageNav.image = image;
```

Hope above code snippet helps..

Comment: It gave me the same results. I think the problem is something with the toolbar. cuz whatever I do, the pic does not go past a certain point

Comment: Try to add the flexible space / fixed space inside the toolbar. 

This will preserve your image on the left hand side and add the space on the right hand side.